# How to do the "Wintersday Skritt Hit" daily achievement more easily?

Tags: guild-wars-2

There is a daily achievement during Wintersday called "Wintersday Skritt Hit". For this, you need to hit 10 Skritts with snowballs during the day. The most common way to do it is to give enough money to Ho-Ho-Tron in Divinity's Reach until he decides to escort the Dolyak to the Crown Pavilion Waypoint, and to throw snowballs to the Skritts attacking the Dolyak. The problem is that **everyone** is doing that. So you find yourself trying to throw snowballs on Skritts with tons of players around them, with:

- Players getting in front of them while you are throwing your snowball, ending up with them being stun and no point for achievement.
- Players throwing snowballs at you trying to aim at the Skritt, ending up with some loss of time, as you are being stunned.
- Players kicking the Skritts away, so you are missing the Skritt.

Also giving away money to Ho-Ho-Tron just for that is kinda a loss, and waiting for other players to do so is obviously taking hours. So is there any other way to do this daily achievement? Like another place where you can pick up snowballs on the ground and throw them at Skritts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hitting friendly skritts around Tyria with snowballs counts toward the achievement (even if they don't have the fall animation).

You can buy [Sealed Package of Snowballs](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sealed_Package_of_Snowballs) (at least 2) in Divinity's Reach and use them to get snowballs anywhere.

You can find friendly skritts in [Kolkorensburg](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Kolkorensburg).

Comment: Oh, I didn't thought about the package, that's smart. Does it also work on hostile Skritts?

Comment: Yes, it also works on hostile skritts tho it is harder because you can't throw snowballs in combat.

Answer (score 1):

using 2 packages :
Goto the silverwastes at the bandid camp there are 2 skritt Sentry.
the left one is right before a rock stand at a straight angle of him and make sure that the aiming grid is full on the rock behind him = guaranteed hit, no fight, no fuss.